# Standalone maven package for hibernate validator annotations

Tags: hibernate-validator

A quick question: is there a stand-alone package for `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.*`?

I want to put these annotations on a DTO package, but don't want to force the user to have hibernate-validator on their class path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what you mean by standalone in this context but here is a link to the `4.3.1` version of [`hibernate-validator`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.3.0.Final).

Adding this to your pom will give you access to all the annotations in `org.hibernate.validator.constraints` package:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

[mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/) is a very good place to search for maven artifacts.

---

**Edit**

Ok now I understand your question, you **only** want the annotations in the `org.hibernate.validator.constraints` as a dependency w/o all the other validation stuff.

Then my answer is no, there is no such thin jar. You will have to use the `hibernate-validator` to get the annotations.

Comment: I guessed so. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom Hibernate Validator constraints you would have to add the actual core classes as well anyways. As long as you rely on Bean Validation constraints (javax.validation.*) it is enough to add the Bean Validation API jar.

What is your concen with adding the hibernate Validator jar?

Comment: I do use a few annotations outside the standard `javax.validation.*` package like Hibernate's `@NotEmpty`. I do not want the `hibernate-validator` package because it's not a required feature of this interface package which is used by many teams. Pushing additional dependencies to them may cause unnecessary complications.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with pushing additional dependencies to the team. And what complications do you think could occur. Basically I am trying to understand why you would like to see a separate artifact for the constraints. Btw, I guess you want to see this - https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HV-553 - implemented. I suggest you state your reasoning for such a feature there.